# Exporting CSV from R, not being read by program until saved by excel

Tags: r, excel, csv, rstudio

I'm exporting CSV files from R, using write.csv
I've also tried various encoding options.
The CSV files open fine and read manually.
However, I need to process these files in another program (METAL https://genome.sph.umich.edu/wiki/METAL) and the program is pretty much unable to recognize the text in the files.
But, when I open the CSV files in excel, and save them again manually with excel-- same name, same place, same encoding, without changing anything except clicking save as CSV, then METAL is able to recognize the text in the CSV files.
I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions how to fix this? It's very cumbersome to go in each file and have to re-save manually.

Comment: Have you tried different `sep` options in write.csv ? Sometimes excel use a alue by default (like tab or comma).

Comment: Did you match METAL's [expectations](https://genome.sph.umich.edu/wiki/METAL_Documentation#Input_File_Separators)?

Comment: @Gowachin yes, I used sep="," in write.table (also just direct write.csv which doesn't accept sep but presumably inserts commas)

Comment: @vaettchen yes I set the command SEPARATOR COMMA, and as I mentioned it works perfectly when I open the csv file in excel and click save.

Comment: What do the R-produced CSV and Excel-produced CSV look like in a plain text editor? Is one quoting values, for example?

Comment: @Brian Hi there, you are right on point! The R-produced CSV includes quotes in a plain text editor and the Excel one produces it without quotes which METAL can interpret. I'll test it out with quote=FALSE. Thanks!